# My chrome extension change itself background not my web page background?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am creating my first chrome extension that manipulate DOM to change page background once i click a button in the extension, but unfortunately, the extension manage to change itself background instead of the web page and i need to know the reason for that:

`manifest.json`

```
{
  "name": "Demo",
  "description": "certain description!",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "background": {
    "service_worker": "background.js"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "storage",
    "declarativeContent",
    "activeTab",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
   }
}
```

`popup.js`

```
 const button = document.getElementById('change-bg');

 button.addEventListener('click, () => {
   let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
   chrome.scripting.executeScript({
     target: { tabId: tab.id },
     function: changeBackground()
  })
 })
}
function changeBackground() {
   document.body.style.background = "blue"
}
```

This extension seems to get the body of the extension not the body of the page, and since i am using `chrome.scripting.executeScripts`, my extension should inject my code into the active page but this doesn't happen.

**What am i doing wrong here?**

Comment: Remove `()` in `function: changeBackground()`

Comment: @wOxxOm thank you this is the second time to help, but can you please explain why this happened?,